# Transmit the images from a Bluetooth camera to the iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I want to implement the feature that "Transmit the images from a Bluetooth camera to the iphone" . So please suggest , how to implement that functionality in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it is possible
Iphones doesn't support any profile that transfers files over bluetooth.

see:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647

One solution is to use the SPP profile to send serial data to the phone. To do this the camera needs to be part of the apple MFI program.
see:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

What profiles does the camera support? 
If it not have apple MFi support this is not possible.